# Add search to 'Parent' dropdown

Tags: custom-post-types, dropdown, hierarchical

I created a product catalog from custom post type pages.

I used it's hierarchy to make menus and submenus. It looked like a great idea at a time...

But now this catalog grew in size and it's very hard to find something in 'Parent' dropdown.

[image: parent dropdown]

Is there a way to add search there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I use it because it's bundled with WooCommerce. It basically adds search box to the `<select>` element. I leave the styling to you. The easiest solution is to add it as a plugin. But you can add it to your theme if you want.

1. Add the `CSS` and `JS` files:

   ```
   <?php
   function custom_scripts_wpse_215576() {
       //Chosen CSS file
       wp_enqueue_style ( 'chose-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/chosen.min.css', array(), '1.4.2', true );
       //Chosen JS file
       wp_enqueue_script( 'chosen-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/chosen.jquery.min.js', array(), '1.4.2', true );
       //Your JS file that will fire up Chosen
       wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/main-script.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
   }

   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts_wpse_215576' );
   ?>
   ```
2. Fire Chosen via the main-script file or anywhere you want:

   ```
   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
       jQuery("#parent_id").chosen({
           search_contains: true
       });
   });
   ```

**Note**: `#parent_id` is the ID of the parent dropdown.

This is the basic setup. By defaults it will add a search box. Consult with the docs to tailor it to your custom setup. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm. Strange the code formatting tools is somehow not formatting my code. Here are pastebins: http://pastebin.com/nbT1X9Wa and http://pastebin.com/LbWfH0GZ .

Comment: I saw your edits. strange indeed...

Comment: I had to make a small modifications to your pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/1P5PmdcC) It works but only for top level pages. Searching for sub-page returns "no result" because they have 'nbsp' characters in front (to make them look like sub-pages).

Comment: Originally I used [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/chosen/) plugin. I tried  the [latest release](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/) but still no luck searching for sub-pages.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will try to tailor it. I almost never use too much nested pages so I guess I've missed it.

Comment: @Boykodev Hi check out the update. Now it should work with nested items. I've added `search_contains` to the options of the JS. [Here is a list](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) of the options. Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iWFxLn31) because again I can't use the formatting...

Comment: @denis.stoyanov if you make use of bullet points as you have done, and you post code directly after that, you need to indent each line with an extra 4 spaces. This will correctly show your code in a code block ;-)

Comment: Awesome! Searching for sub-pages works now! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @PieterGoosen Aah, I see. I thought I was going crazy... Thank you very much!